# my vbulletin login api wont work through file_get_contents

Tags: php, vbulletin

I have made a script to login into Vbulletin through API

here is the code

```
<?php    
include 'connector.class.php';
    if ($connector==null)
    {
        $connector = new vbConnector();
    }
    $do=$_GET['do'];
    if ($do=="login")
    {

        $user_name=$_GET['username'];
        $user_pass=$_GET['password'];
        $res= $connector->doLogin($user_name,$user_pass, 1);
        echo  $res;
    }
```

When I request this through url eg (http://example.com?do=login&username=test&password=test) it works perfectly and everything is fine

How ever when I try to curl or file_get_content the same url , it never logs me is

Here is some of my trials

```
<?php
    $opts = array('http' => array('header'=> 'Cookie: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']."\r\n"));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
echo file_get_contents("http://192.168.5.55/vb_api/index.php?do=login&username=test&password=test");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not pass `$context` in your file_get_contents call. Try this:

```
<?php
    $opts = array('http' => array('header'=> 'Cookie: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']."\r\n"));
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    echo file_get_contents("http://192.168.5.55/vb_api/index.php?do=login&username=test&password=test",false,$context);
?>
```

I know this is old but I just found this related link to my post, hope that solves your problem.